# Docker force usage of volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I know that you can specify a volume inside the dockerfile, but I see the problem that the user is not required to create such a volume.

What if he forgot to specify a volume and than there are many, possibly expensive to create, files saved there, but they are not persistent, because there is no volume specified?

So my question is if it is possible to force the user to create a volume for that mountpoint, or at least check at start time (inside the container) if there is a volume mounted, so that it can react to the missing volume?

EDIT: With the new information that there are automatic created unnnamed volumes I would also accept a user-side solution (not changing the container in such a ways that he checks the volume, but a docker-deamon settings which warn/prevents me from creating unnamed volumes by mistake.

Comment: If your `Dockerfile` has a `VOLUME` instruction and no named volume is mounted during the run then `docker` will create an [anonymous volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/#more-details-about-mount-types) for the data, the volume is never "missing". You can inspect the containers mounts for the names of the volumes `docker inspect mycontainer --format "{{range .Mounts}}{{.Name}}{{end}}"`.

Comment: Oh, I still hope for an answer to my question, because I think that these id-names volumes are no place for important data.

Comment: If you catch yourself using an anonymous volume you can move the data to a named volume then recreate the container using the named volume.

Comment: @masseyb That is the part I know, but what I ask for is a feature which catch the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `VOLUME` declaration is the best you can do here.

In general, a container cannot force itself to be run with any particular options.  You could make a similar argument that a container "must" be run with published port or with an attached stdin to be useful, but Docker doesn't allow an image to force these on either.  (And more importantly, an image can't require direct access to the host filesystem, host networking, or privileged mode.)

As @masseyb notes in a comment, the key effect of the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive is to create a new anonymous volume on the given directory if nothing else is mounted there.  `docker volume ls` will show it and you should be able to use the volume ID directly in `docker run -v` options, so you won't actually lose data here.  (There doesn't seem to be a command to give a name to the volume, surprisingly.)

In principle it's possible to check some things in an entrypoint wrapper script, but that won't work well for this volume case.  The container can't tell whether a directory is an automatically-created anonymous volume or a new empty named volume.

(Also remember that volumes, including automatically-created anonymous volumes, are never committed to images.  In your Dockerfile you can't change the directory content after you declare it a `VOLUME`; if an end user tries to `docker commit` a derived image it won't include the volume data.  Unless you're *sure* it's what you want, I usually advise against declaring `VOLUME`.  The case you describe in the question is pretty much the one case where it's useful.)

Comment: You are right, the problem is bigger than I thought. The same problem occurs for ports, you can expose it, but it doesn't do anything. The user doesn't get remembered that the port/volume is important. For ports there is al least a option to expose all ports to some arbitrary ports.